# Как расширить контекстное меню?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как добавить меню рядом с "копировать-вставить и др"?

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать программу для обучения иностранных языков. Есть база данных Access, поля слово-перевод и др.

Меня интересует, как мне добавить в Windows значение "Добавить слово" рядом с "Вставить", "Копировать" и др. при нажатии правой кнопки на этом слове. Я хочу, читая текст на иностранном языке, клацнуть прав кнопкой мыши и нажать - добавить и что б это слово, было добавлено в мою базу в поле "Слово" базы данных.

1. Как добавить меню?
2. Как узнать выделенное в данный момент слово (и занести его в базу)?

Comment: "как мне добавить в виндосе".

Comment: вы собираетесь написать программу которая работает с базой или хотите выправить под свои нужды сам Microsoft Access?

Comment: переопредели в элементе управления ContextMenu.

Comment: Я собираюсь написать программу которая работает с базой.
а как добавить выбранное слово в базу?(точнее как мне узнать,что б потом его вставить?)

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в какой конкретно помощи нуждаетесь.

Answer (score 1):

> как мне добавить в Windows

одна из первых ссылок на одном из поисковых сайтов (название которого Вам ничего не скажет) намекает на:

[Добавьте к контекстному меню Вас это Окна Проводника](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10104/Add-a-context-menu-to-the-Windows-Explorer)

[Простое контекстное меню раковины](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15171/Simple-shell-context-menu)

Переведено одним из переводчиков.

Для MS Word можно посмотреть [вот эту ссылку с небольшим примером](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246837/How-to-add-a-menu-item-in-Microsoft-Office-Word-7).

С браузером история интересней: по идее, браузер не должен иметь доступа к локальной машине из-за политик безопасности, поэтому получить доступ к БД будет проблематично, да честно говоря, неправильно.
Но в chrome, наверное, можно попробовать через [npapi](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html).

Правильней сделать плагин/расширение, которое будет обращаться к какой-либо веб службе, а уже сама служба будет писать в БД и танцевать ламбаду. Наверняка ее можно развернуть и на вашей локальной машине и даже доступ из браузера будет.

Comment: спасибо большое, это относится только к проводнику? я хочу в ворде или браузере читать и добавлять слова

Comment: обновил ответ